# ACF gallery hook?

Tags: gallery, advanced-custom-fields

When updating a gallery with a new image or deleting an image, is there a hook which gets called?

With a standard image field there's 
`add_filter('acf/update_value/type=image', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same filter, just replace the type:

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/type=gallery', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```

All fields extend the same base class, so they also share the same basic filters.